# History of the expression "Moses basket"

Tags: etymology, phrases

The expression "Moses basket" is clearly an allusion to the biblical story. But what is the history of this expression? When was the expression first used to mean a portable cradle for a baby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://www.oed.com) (subscription required) shows this in the *Times* in 1924.  It also indicates comparison to a French term with the same meaning: *moïse* from 1889.

Comment: What is the French term?

Comment: The answer gives it; _moïse_ (the French version of _Moses_).

Comment: I don’t understand the French reference. The OED says “ Moses basket  n.  [compare French moïse (1889)] ”.  But how am I meant to do that comparison? Is 1889 the date of a quote we haven’t been given? Moïse  is just the French for Moses as far as I know.

Comment: The French *moïse* means *Moses basket*.  See https://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/moïse  The French *Moïse* means *Moses*.